# How to separate output of sdiff into three files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sdiff

I need to separate the output of
`sdiff -s file1 file2` into three files. 
The modified content should be stored in `Changedfound.txt`,
the appended content should be stored in `Append.txt`,
and the deleted content should be stored in `Delete.txt`. 
This separation should be based on the symbols
'`|`' (vertical bar), '`>`' (greater than), and '`<`' (less than).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` with subshells to do this.  If you have data like this:

```
$ cat file1 
0
1
2
3

$ cat file2
1
2
3 4
5

$ sdiff -s file1 file2
0                                 <
3                                 | 3 4
                                  > 5
```

You could pipe into `tee`, and match that in a subshell running something like `sed`:

```
$ sdiff -s file1 file2 | \
  tee >(sed -ne 's/\s*<$//p' > Delete.txt) | \
  tee >(sed -ne 's/^\s*>\s//p' > Append.txt ) | \
  tee >(sed -ne 's/^.*\s|\s//p' > ChangedFound.txt)

$ cat Delete.txt
0

$ cat Append.txt
5

$ cat ChangedFound.txt
3 4
```

---

PS.  There is a better way to do this with `awk`, so you don't have to parse every line 3 times.

Comment: ,what if my files also having some condition of greater than ,less than and OR conditions,then in that case it will redirect those files also.I want to ignore them.

Comment: The first situation (`\s*<$`) only matches lines where there is at least one space, the `<`, then and end-of-line.  That should filter out most conditions. `^\s*>\s` only matches lines with only whitespaces before the `>` and then at least one space afterwards.  `^.*\s|\s` is a bit tougher because it really only checks for the first pipe `|` which is surrounded by spaces.